# How to Delete Visible Rows After Filtering Run Time Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to create a macro where I make a copies of a worksheet based on a column and delete out what doesn't equal the current value I am looping through.

My data may or may not be in a table in the original worksheet. I need to make a copy of the original worksheet and then delete out in order to maintain the column groups I created in the original worksheet.

```
Sub FilterCopy()
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    If Ws.FilterMode Then Ws.ShowAllData
    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
       For Each cl In Ws.Range("A2", Ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
       If Not .exists(cl.Value) Then
        .Add cl.Value, Nothing
        Ws.Copy
        Range("A1").AutoFilter 1, "<>" & cl.Value
        'The code below gives me the error
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        Range("A1").AutoFilter
        Range("A1").AutoFilter
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "U:\Test\" & cl.Value & ".xlsx", 51
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
     End If
  Next cl
End With
End Sub
```

Run-time error '1004':

> Delete method of Range class failed

Comment: Do you get the error when your data is in a Table, when it's not or both?

Comment: When it is a table it is "delete method of Range class failed" when it is not a table it is still Run time error 1004 but it says "cannot use that command on overlapping sections"

Comment: I think the answer I gave should solve both cases, but let me know if it only works in one case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your problem is caused by the fact that the rows you are trying to delete are discontinuous. Indeed, Excel-VBA has difficulties when it's time to handle ranges that don't touch and form different areas.

To solve this issue, you can process the range one area at the time like this:

```
Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = <Your Range Specification>

For i = MyRange.Areas.Count To 1 Step -1
    MyRange.Areas(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next i
```

It's important to go from the last (bottom) to the first area by using for loop in decreasing order. This will avoid the problem where rows you want to delete have changed their number after shifting up due to previous rows being deleted.

Regarding the range, I would avoid using `AutoFilter`. Even if it can return a range, this feature doesn't seem to be well documented ([See MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter)). For that reason and for simplicity, I would suggest you to define the range as such:

```
Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A2"), ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).SpecialCells(xlVisible).EntireRow
```

Note that it's important to include this right after you make the copy of the sheet to make sure that `ActiveSheet` is referring to the correct sheet.